# Is it possible to load part(content) of an angularjs app using ajax?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

Is it possible to load part(content) of an angularjs app using ajax? if it is, please direct me to some topics i could study to succesfully do it.

Comment: By parts do you mean entire modules with controllers or just view partials?

Comment: partials with modules and controllers, whenever i call a partial in my  ajax the modules and controllers does not load in my ajax page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. AngularJS is a Single-Page Application framework, which means everything should be loaded once, then AngularJS taking care of changing routing, views, etc.

The only possibility not to load everything is when the server is in charge of rendering views, thus using AngularJS not as SPA, but just for its templating abilities and component abilities (directives).

So you can't load partially using ajax.

Comment: how about if i wanna load the whole angularjs app inside the ajax page?